# add row to a csv file with python

Tags: python, file, csv

I have two csv files that each have 2 columns, one of them being the date. I want to add the second column of the second file to the first file, resulting a file with 3 columns.

I did it by creating a new file and appending the data to it this way:

```
import csv

coinsfile = open('total-bitcoins.csv', newline='')
pricesfile = open('market-price.csv', newline='')

coins = csv.reader(coinsfile, delimiter=',')
prices = csv.reader(pricesfile, delimiter=',')

with open('result.csv', 'w') as res:
    for coin_row, price_row in zip(coins, prices):
        line = str(coin_row[0]) + ',' + str(coin_row[1]) + ',' + str(price_row[1])
        res.append(line)
```

The code runs without any errors but the result is a csv file which is completely empty.

Where am I making the mistake, or is there a better way to do this job?

Comment: `res.append(line)` res is a file handle, you forgot the csv part

Comment: You're making a mistake because you're using `csv.reader()` only. If you want write to a file, you need the `writer()` object.

Comment: could you please explain more? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: `res.write(line+"\n")` should fix it, but it's dirty

Comment: This _doesn't_ run without errors, unless one of your input files is empty.

Comment: If one of your input files is empty, then the `zip` is empty, so the `for` loop never loops, so you get an empty file. So, that's the problem you actually need to fix. Once you fix that, you'll have a second problem: `res.append` will raise `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'`. You could fix that as Jean-François Fabre suggested—or, better, using a `csv.writer` as roganjosh suggested.

Comment: @abarnert that or the infamous "windows opens and closes immediately" error with no time to read the error message :) leaving an empty file as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` is a file handle, so the `append` method doesn't apply to it. So there's an attribute error while the output file is opened, which results in an empty output file (or, yes, one of the input files is empty, ending `zip` immediately, but this answer explains how to fix the *next* issues)

A quickfix would be:

```
res.write(line+"\n")
```

but the best way would be to flatten the result of `zip` and feed it to a `csv.writer` object (using a comprehension to generate each row by addition of both input csv rows)

```
import csv

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline="") as res, open('total-bitcoins.csv', newline='') as coinsfile, open('market-price.csv', newline='') as pricesfile:
    coins = csv.reader(coinsfile)
    prices = csv.reader(pricesfile)
    cw = csv.writer(res)
    cw.writerows(coin_rows+price_row for coin_row, price_row in zip(coins, prices))
```

note that `newline=""` is required when writing your files (Python 3) to avoid the infamous blank line "bug" when running windows

I have added the input files in the `with` statement to ensure that the inputs are closed when exiting it. And also removed the delimiter parameter as comma is the default.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to satisfy this need would be using a library like pandas. Using pandas, adding a column to an existing file would be as easy as loading the file into a dataframe, and adding the required column to it in just one line.

Adding can be done by mere assignment, or through join/merge methods.